# how to ignore error "ERROR *** Token 0x2d (AreaN) found in NAME formula" from pyspark.pandas.read_excel(engine = xlrd) reading xls file with #REF

Tags: pyspark, databricks, xlrd, pyspark-pandas

I am trying to read an xls file which containts #REF values.
When I try to read the file with "pyspark.pandas.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name = 'sheet_name', engine='xlrd', convert_float=False, dtype='str').to_spark()" I get the error "ERROR *** Token 0x2d (AreaN) found in NAME formula".

I assume the error is occurring due to the #REF values in the file, so my questions is if there is any way I can ignore the error and convert #REF to None? I need to read it into pyspark.

Thank you!

I tried pyspark.pandas.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name = 'sheet_name', engine='xlrd', convert_float=False, dtype='str', errors='coerce').to_spark() and expected it to read the file, but get the error "read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errors'".